# Does your current character selection affect multi-player pack contents?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

When I was playing my infiltrator, my packs seemed to pull lots of sniper rifles and sniper rifle upgrades.  Now that I'm playing other characters I'm getting a more eclectic selection of firearms and upgrades.

**Am I just suffering from a bad case of confirmation bias, or are the packs smart enough to give you the items you might find more useful?**

Comment: I doubt there's enough data to reach a conclusion, but I personally doubt EA would undermine its profits by giving you the good stuff for free.

Comment: If there wasn't just enough good stuff in the packs, there would be no motive to spend any real money on them.

Comment: I started with an adept and got everything EXCEPT assault rifles. I have a shotgun, that I never use at VII ...

Comment: @CaulynDarr the Sims franchise is evidence to the contrary.

Comment: I'd lean towards confirmation bias here. Started on a Vanguard and my first 3 weapons and upgraded weapons were sniper rifles. >,> Was not happy, haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing that changes your chances of getting a certain weapon from a pack. Their contents is random, and what you are getting is just good luck. If you were a different class, those packs would still contain sniper rifles and SR upgrades, because they are *completely random*.